# Checkboxes inserting error

Tags: vba, checkbox

I'm working on a sheet where I create checkboxes.

I use the following code to create the checkbox:

```
Sub AddCheckbox()

Dim vert As Integer
Dim MyTop  As Integer
vert = Sheets("Overview").Range("P2").Value

Sheets("Database").Activate
MyTop = 15 * (vert - 1)
    ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(770, MyTop, 1, 1).Select
        With Selection
            .Caption = ""
            .Value = xlOff
            .LinkedCell = "K" & vert
            .Display3DShading = False
        End With

End Sub
```

This piece  works perfectly until I call it from some other part of the script. At this point I'm getting the message "name is not defined" (roughly translated). Why?

When the script directly starts, a checkbox is created and the linked cell works fine.
When the script is called, a checkbox is created with a caption and without link to the cell.

Comment: make sure both sheets *`Overview`* and *`Database`* exist. check that there always is a **valid** value in `Overview` sheet `Range("P2")`. Make sure variable `MyTop` exist. `.LinkedCell` may need to be qualified (sheet name before K). Can't think of anything else

Comment: Alright, checked all your suggestions, except for one i'm not 100% sure.
"Make sure MyTop exist" with following code should be sufficient, right?

    `Dim MyTop As Integer` combined with 
    `MyTop = 15 * (vert -1)`

Sorry for the poor formatting

Comment: yes you have the `MyTop` sorry Ive missed that. I can't reproduce the error so I can't work out in what circumstances you're getting the error :/ can you explain when the error happens?

Comment: apparently I figured it out.
Since I Activate the `Database` sheet, I had to Activate the `Overview` sheet again in the other script. It´s a bit of magic to me though :) Thanks for the suggestions anyway!

Comment: [INTERESTING READ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Comment: Thanks, interesting read indeed!